# Laravel return id 0 after saving

Tags: laravel

I tried saving a data into mysql with guid as my primary key, why does laravel return a 0 value for id when it was save as guid?
  anyone have this problem before? this works on laravel 4 but not on 5

```
   $data = new Question;
        $data->id = \Uuid::generate(4);
        $data->value = $question;
        if($data->save())
          return $data;
        return null;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel all return ID become 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603773/laravel-all-return-id-become-0)

Answer (score 5):

As mimo said make sure the id is not auto incremented and add this statement in your model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Check the note in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: Have you tried using the create method on the Question model instead of save ?

Comment: yes, either way it wont return the gui id. I had decide to use the auto increment for now

Answer (score 0):

ID has to be one of the `fillable` fields in your model. If not it is protected. Also make sure it has no auto incrent.

Comment: when I put it on fillable fields it outputs {}

Comment: What type has it when you migrate it? Increment or integer? (I mean the migration file, not the mysql table). To find the problem please post your user model and your migration file.

Comment: I use string in my migration

Comment: And what is written in your database, 0 or the real string? Maybe it's also a problem by naming it `id`

Comment: a real string guid, I don't know why it really doens't work. I just decide to move to increments for now.