# Laravel all return ID become 0

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a problem with all my queries with a `varchar` ID returning an integer.

For example,a query which should return `C-1451963448-MjL` returns instead 0.

My query:

```
$transaction = Transaction::with('user')->get();
return response()->json($transaction);
```

which returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "user_id": 8,
    "amount": "56164.00",
    "created_at": "2016-01-05 10:10:48",
    "user": {
      "id": 8,
      "facebook_id": null,
      "first_name": "Alta",
      "last_name": "Keebler",
    }
  },
]
```

the transaction id becoming 0. Last time I tried it succeeded, but now every ID with `varchar` returns 0 instead of the real value.

I've tried to `foreach` the get query, and yes the id is `0`. 
I also tried to `dd($transaction)` when i checked it, it return me with correct ID.

What should I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Set `$incrementing` to false on your model.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

The casts system checks if this is set to true, if it is, it will try to cast the the `key` field to an int.

Comment: its working!. but this only happen today. it's odd. btw thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the simple answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You make my day..:)