# Laravel model is created with id = 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am having problem with eloquent.
Here's some code:

```
$BaseTask = $TaskClass::create([
        'user_id' => $User->id,
        'task_type' => $this->task_type,
        'name' => $this->settings['name'],
        'task_' . $this->social_network . '_list_id' => $task_list_id,
]);
$BaseTask->accounts()->attach($account_id);
```

The problem is that **SOMETIMES** the last line fails with a foreign key constraint fails - it tries to update pivot table with query

```
insert into pivot ('account_id', 'task_id') values (289530, 0))
```

So somehow:

```
$BaseTask->id=0;
```

but i have property:

```
$incrementing=true;
```

Maybe someone faced such issue, any help appreciated!

Comment: Is it configured correctly on your database?

Comment: Yep, as this happens only sometimes(~5% of cases), maybe there's some db's bad behaviour?

Comment: The attach() method is only for many-to-many, for other relationships there's save() and associate()

Comment: Yep, i have many to many relationship

Comment: @МаксимСарвилин Try with $BaseTask->accounts()->associate($account_id); and let me know working or not

Comment: associate() won't work as it's many-to-many

Comment: Does the `$TaskClass` row actually get inserted in that case?

Comment: Not sure if it exists right in that moment but yes - row exists in db, so only child entities are not created. Furthermore - i'm catching exceptions  - so from frontend - i  just see my custom error - but when click to "save my task"  on more time it's created normally, so in result i have duplicated tasks but the one with error doesn't have related entities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel all return ID become 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603773/laravel-all-return-id-become-0)

Answer (score 9):

I have experienced the same issue, you need to put:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

on the model.

Answer (score 0):

use `save()` method instead, since you don't have many to many relationship. If you do have many to many use `sync()` function then. Also go to database.php file set  mysql`strict` to `false`

Comment: okay then Use sync() function I thonk it will solv the issue with id's as well.

Comment: hm do you think that "changing method" will solve the problem of 0 id of parent model?

Comment: if you want to prevent zero value on id; You could set the initial AUTO_INCREMENT value to a positive integer - but I believe it starts with 1 anyway. Just to be sure:  ALTER TABLE table_name_here AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;

Comment: auto_increment is already set to tasks table - it's production